# Getting input from text file and storing into array but text file contains more than 20.000 strings

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

Getting inputs from a text file and storing it into an array but text file contains more than 20.000 strings. I'm trying to read strings from the text file and store them into a huge-sized array. How can I do that?

I can not use vectors.
Is it possible to do it without using a hash table?

Afterward, I will try to find the most frequently used words using sorting.

Comment: Why you cannot use vectors?

Comment: @kiner_shah - Guess NOBUD is a student being taught "the basics" first, and cannot use the simple, easy to use ways until the "advanced course" coming later. You know `std::vector<std::string>` uses templates, so advanced by definition.

Comment: it's a requirement of the challange

Comment: So you're talking about an c style array. In this case, you would first identify the number of entries the array is going to have and afterwards initialize an array on the heap using your previously aquired information about its size.

Comment: @NOBUD, your question can lead to opinion based answers - not desired on SO. You may want to edit the post and make things a bit specific.

Comment: @NOBUD Any other similar restrictions? Anyway, using any container data structure of `std::string` objects may be inefficient. If the read strings won't be mutated, I would read the whole file content into a single `char` array and then build some "index" data structure above it. Such as an array of `string_view`s.

Comment: to find most frequently used words you do not need the whole file at once in memory. You can read a chunk, process it, continue with the next chunk.

Comment: @kiner_shah So basically, My aim is to store a huge amount of strings into an array or dynamic array maybe a hash table ( I'm not sure about that part). Later,  I want to find the most frequent word in the array before finding the most frequent word. There is another text file that has stop_words. I need to subtract stop words from the main text file

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number can you enlighten me about that solution? Any reference link or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You requirement is to NOT use any standard container like for example a  `std::vector` or a `std::unordered_map`.

In this case we need to create a dynamic container by ourself. That is not complicated. And we can use this even for storing strings. So, I will even not use `std::string` in my example.

I created some demo for you with ~700 lines of [code](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/Stackoverflow/blob/main/0001).

We will first define the term "capacity". This is the number of elements that could be stored in the container. It is the currently available space. It has nothing to do, how many elements are really stored in the container.

But there is one and the most important functionality of a dynamic container. It must be able to grow. And this is always necessary, if we want to store add more elements to the container, as its capacity.

So, if we want to add an additional element at the end of the container, and if the number of elements is >= its capacity, then we need to reallocate bigger memory and then copy all the old elements to the new memory space. For such events, we will usually double the capacity. This should prevent frequent reallocations and copying activities.

Let me show you one example for a `push_back` function, which could be implemented like this:

```
template <typename T>
void DynamicArray<T>::push_back(const T& d) {               // Add a new element at the end
    if (numberOfElements >= capacity) {                     // Check, if capacity of this dynamic array is big enough
        capacity *= 2;                                      // Obviously not, we will double the capacity
        T* temp = new T[capacity];                          // Allocate new and more memory
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < numberOfElements; ++k)
            temp[k] = data[k];                              // Copy data from old memory to new memory
        delete[] data;                                      // Release old memory
        data = temp;                                        // And assign newly allocated memory to old pointer
    }
    data[numberOfElements++] = d;                           // And finally, store the given data at the end of the container
}
```

This is a basic approach. I use templates in order to be able to store any type in the dynamic array.

You could get rid of the templates, by deleting all template stuff and replacing "T" with your intended data type.

But, I would not do that. See, how easy we can create a "String" class. We just `typedef` a dynamic array for `char`s as "String".

```
using String = DynamicArray<char>;
```

will give us basic string functionality. And if we want to have a dynamic array of strings later, we can write:

```
using StringArray = DynamicArray<String>;
```

and this gives us a `DynamicArray<DynamicArray<char>>`. Cool.

For this special classes we can overwrite some operators, which will make the handling and our life even more simple.

Please look in the provided [code](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/Stackoverflow/blob/main/0001)

---

And, to be able to use the container in the typical C++ environment, we can add full iterator capability. That makes life even more simple.

This needs really some typing effort, but is not complicated. And, it will make life really simpler.

---

You also wanted to create a hash map. For counting words.

For that we will create a key/value pair. The key is the String that we defined above and the value will be the frequency counter.

We implement a hash function which should be carefully selected to work with strings, has a high entropy and give good results for the bucket size of the hash map.

The hash map itself is a dynamic container. We will also add iterator functionality to it.

---

For all this I drafted some 700 lines of code for you. You can take this as an example for your further studies.

It can also be easily enhanced with additional functionality.

But caveat: I did only some basic tests and I even used raw pointers for owned memory. This can be done in a schoolproject to learn some dynamic memory management, but not in reality.

Additionlly. You can replace all this code, by simply using `std::string`, `std::vector` and `std::unordered_map`. Nobody would use such code and reinvent the wheel.

But it may give you some ideas on how to implement similar things.

Because Stackoverlof limits the answer size to 32000 characters, I will put the main part on github.

Please click [here](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/Stackoverflow/blob/main/0001).

I will just show you main so that you can see how easy the solution can be used:

```
int main() {

    // Open file and check, if it could be opened
    std::ifstream ifs{ "r:\\test.txt" };
    if (ifs) {

        // Define a dynamic array for strings
        StringArray stringArray{};

        // Use overwritten extraction operator and read all strings from the file to the dynamic array
        ifs >> stringArray;

        // Create a dynamic hash map
        HashMap hm{};

        // Now count the frequency of words
        for (const String& s : stringArray)
            hm[s]++;

        // Put the resulting key/value pairs into a dynamic array
        DynamicArray<Item> items(hm.begin(), hm.end());

        // Sort in descending order by the frequency
        std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), [](const Item& i1, const Item& i2) { return i1.count > i2.count; });

        // SHow resulton screen
        for (const auto& [string, count] : items) 
            std::cout << std::left << std::setw(20) << string << '\t' << count << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Could not open source file\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will work on it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to keep the whole file in memory to count frequency of words. You only need to keep a single entry and some data structure to count the frequencies, for example a `std::unordered_map<std::string,unsigned>`.

Not tested:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,unsigned> processFileEntries(std::ifstream& file) { 
    std::unordered_map<std::string,unsigned> freq;
    std::string word;
    
    while ( file >> entry ) {
              ++freqs[entry];
    }
    return freq;
}
```

For more efficient reading or more elaborated processing you could also read chunks of the file (eg 100 words), process chunks, and then continue with the next chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using C-Style / raw arrays you could do something like:

```
const size_t number_of_entries = count_entries_in_file();

//Make sure we actually have entries
assert(number_of_entries > 0);

std::string* file_entries = new std::string[number_of_entries];

//fill file_entries with the files entries
//...

//release heap memory again, so we don't create a leak

delete[] file_entries;
file_entries = nullptr;
```

Comment: `assert(number_of_entries > 0)` does not mean "only do the following if there are any entries in the file", but "if `count_entries_in_file` returns 0 we have made a programming mistake".

Comment: `if(file_entries)` is superfluous. A failing `new` expression would throw an exception.

Comment: @DanielLangr If you're handling the exception sure. Anyway, delete deals with null too so it was still unnecessary, so I removed it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thats correct. I just put the assert in to make clear you to some checking. What kind of checks is up to OP, so I will leave the assert there.

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet If you are not handling exceptions thrown by the `new`, the program execution never gets to that `delete` at the end in case of error..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `std::map` to get the frequency of each word in your text file. One example for reference is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputFile("input.txt");
    std::map<std::string, unsigned> freqMap;
    std::string line, word; 
    if(inputFile)
    {
        while(std::getline(inputFile, line))//go line by line 
        {
            std::istringstream ss(line);
            
            while(ss >> word)//go word by word 
            {
                ++freqMap[word]; //increment the count value corresponding to the word 
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "input file cannot be opened"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    //print the frequency of each word in the file 
    for(auto myPair: freqMap)
    {
        std::cout << myPair.first << ": " << myPair.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/l0imm1SMx).

Comment: Hi again. This answer completely ignores the questions. And, typical pattern again. Just dumping code. Maybe you should read on meta, how to write answers. Explanation is always needed. And maybe you should read the question again. The clear request was that **no standard container** shall be used. You should either update your answer or better delete it. What is the purpose of this answer? And do not forget to take a deep breath, before answering.

Comment: @ArminMontigny **a)** Again you're misinterpreting OP's question. Nowhere in OP's code does it say that *"no standard container shall be used"*. What it says at one point is that *"i cannot use vectors"*. And in my code there is no `vector` involved. Read the question carefully before commenting on someone's answer(specially mine). In fact, the OP specifically asked *"If is it possible to do it without hash table?"*. But that doesn't mean that we must not use hash table. The OP has a query that whether it can be done without a hash table.

Comment: Continued.. And i have shown one method using hash table. It is upto him/her to choose this option based on the usability of this method. **To prove** my point that it is indeed a query, In the comment section OP said *"My aim is to store a huge amount of strings into an array or dynamic array **maybe a hash table ( I'm not sure about that part)**."* So that is why added the answer.

Comment: Continued.. **b)** Also the appropriate explanation is given in the comments of my answer. Did you even take a look at the code? I have given explanation which i thought is enough.  And FYI the other answer by `463035818_is_not_a_number` also uses a `unordered_map`. There is nothing wrong in presenting an alternative way of solving a problem. Specially if the OP is not sure(may unaware) that using a hash table can really simplify the problem